# Performance Problems with Azure Websites in North Europe

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a few sites that are running in the Azure Web Sites (North Europe region) at the moment, over the last 12 or so hours I have noticed some really poor performance, anyone seeing the same thing at the moment?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing logged in the Azure Service Dashboard for service degradation or outage. Perhaps you may raise a support ticket with Azure [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/contact/) to see whats wrong...